# Georss feed xcode

Tags: xcode, rss, feed, georss

first of all I´m from spain so sorry for my english;)
I´m trying to do a georss feed and my first problem starts with the url of the feed, with my code I can parse a lot of urls like http://feeds.feedburner.com/applesfera but I can´t load this one:

http://www.zaragoza.es/georref/rdf/hilo/ver_Incidencias?tipo=3&srsname=wgs84

My code for this is:(error code 5)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if ([stories count] == 0) 
{

    NSString * path = @"http://www.zaragoza.es/georref/rdf/hilo/ver_Incidencias?tipo=3&srsname=wgs84";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }
}


- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL{  
stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[rssParser parse];      }
```

Any suggestion why is that?

Thanks;)

Comment: it´s ok, the xml file was damaged.